# Sony PMB blurs pictures automatically

Tags: images

When clicking a picture into Picture Motion Browser (PMB) window (enlarge it to fit to window/screen), the picture is always presented sharply at first one second but soon turns smoothing/blurring/flattering itself, no matter if I re-install it or change computers from home to office.

I was surprised to find that the same situation can be [observed in Sony's tutorial film](http://support.d-imaging.sony.co.jp/www/disoft/int/pmb/feature/edit/movie/autocorrect.html).

Please just watch how PMB blurs the tile's lines on the left hand side after reading it into the application window - about one second afterwards.

Moreover, when adjusting sharpness of the picture with PMB, the adjustment effect will be eliminated (smoothed out) by the aforementioned smoothing/blurring/flattering "function".

It's really bad for me because other browsers I have cannot read Nex-5 films. So now I have to use two browsers, one for still pictures and PMB for films. Very annoying.

Anybody know how to fix the problem?

I tried to contact Sony developers, yet they claimed the problems were due to large size pictures or some "preview effect", which was not acceptable and didn't get me anywhere.